# How to extract String from Pair<Boolean,String> using Java Stream.of?

Tags: java, string, list, java-stream

I have a `Stream<Function<String,  Pair<Boolean, String>>` criteria is a varargs of lambda expressions

```
Stream.of(criteria)
      .map(func -> func.apply(input))
      .filter(result -> result.getValue0() == false);
```

I want to extract the String if `getValue0 == false`. I want to concatenate the string in the end. Can anyone give me any pointers?

Comment: What is `getValue0()`? Is `Pair` your custom-defined class or from any library? What about a sample `input` and an output that you expect?

Comment: @Deadpool You've edited the question such as the code and the requirements contradict further, might want to clarify with OP first.

Comment: @Deadpool True, `Collectors.joining` is a good hint towards concatenating strings while using streams, just that the question itself wasn't really clear about the code shared.

Comment: @Naman Sorry I'm a noob at asking question, sorry that it wasn't clear. Pair is from org.javatuples. A sample input can be "ABC" and "XYZ", and an output would be "ABC, XYZ"

Answer (score 0):

What you already have in your code snippet is that the function is applied to each of criteria. Then you are filtering for only those, that have a value of true. This seems to be the reverse of what you want. Maybe flip the result, as in `result -> !result.getValue0()`? Than you will need another `map` operation to get a stream of string instead of pairs and a `collect` operation to join them. As pointed out in the comments, take a look at [Collectors.joining](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#joining--).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure the type of criteria, a `List<Function>` or `Function`. Whatever you can try the two methods as follows.

```
public static class Pair<F, S> {
    private F first;
    private S second;

    public Pair(F first, S second) {
        this.first = first;
        this.second = second;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    // criteria is a function
    Function<String, Pair<Boolean, String>> criteria = (x) -> new Pair<>(true, x);
    Stream.of(criteria)
            .map(func -> func.apply(null))
            .filter(result -> !result.first)
            .map(result -> result.second)
            .collect(Collectors.joining(","));

    // criteria is a list
    List<Function<String, Pair<Boolean, String>>> criterias = new ArrayList<>();
    criterias.stream()
            .map(func -> func.apply(null))
            .filter(result -> !result.first)
            .map(result -> result.second)
            .collect(Collectors.joining(","));
}
```